# Changing the order in which <div>'s overlap each other with jQuery mouse-click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make specified div's on my page interactive and thus, change focus (come to the foreground if you will) when clicked.  Essentially, I would like the div's to act much like the windows do on a computer running Microsoft Windows.

This is what I've come up with so far using z-index and it does work, sort of.  The problem is that the div's appear to have their own "order" so to speak when it comes to overlapping each other based on where they are placed in the HTML.

For instance, if you click "Div2" then "Div1", you can see that "Div2" ends up actually going back behind "Div3" rather than staying in front of it as it previously was.  I'd like order to be retained as clicked.  If you click Div2, it should be in the front, then you click Div1 and it would then be in front of Div2, etc.

Any ideas on a way around this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

```js
// Global vars
var lastFocused;
    
// When left mousedown on a ".window" element, remove the ".window-focus" class from id
// specified in the global var "lastFocused".  Next, update the global var "lastFocused"
// with the most recently clicked element id.  Lastly, add the ".window-focus" class to
// the id specified in global var "lastFocused". 
$('.window').mousedown(function () {
  $(lastFocused).removeClass('window-focus');
  lastFocused = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
  $(lastFocused).addClass('window-focus');
});
    
// Make all ".window" elements resizable and draggable.
$('.window').draggable({containment: '#container'}).resizable({containment: '#container'});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Roboto;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #c9c9c9;
        font-size: 1em;
        overflow: hidden;
}
    
.window {
        position: absolute !important;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        background-color: #222;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        z-index: 1;
}
    
#div1 { top: 20px; left: 20px; }
#div2 { top: 60px; left: 60px; }
#div3 { top: 100px; left: 100px; }
    
.window-focus { z-index: 2; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="window" id="div1">ONE</div>
<div class="window" id="div2">TWO</div>
<div class="window" id="div3">THREE</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are always giving the the currently clicked `div` a `z-index` of `2`, which does bring it to the front, but then when you remove that class from an element it simply goes back to it's original `z-index`. You need that last-applied `z-index` not to change and have the next-clicked element get a `z-index` that is one higher than the previous one.

Just keep track of the last `z-index` assigned to the last-clicked `div` element and increment it by one after each assignment so that the next clicked element will get a higher `z-index` assigned to it.

**NOTES:**

- There is no need for the `lastFocused` variable, the `.window-focus`
  CSS selector, or to assign a `z-index:1` to the `.window` elements.
- You were exactly right about elements having an implicit `z-index`
  based on where they are in the HTML. For sibling elements, the `z-index` is simply based on the sequence. The earlier in the sequence, the lower the `z-index`. But, it's more complex when you start working with elements that don't share the same parent. See the **[stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)** for details.
- JQuery recommends using the `element.on("eventName", callback)`
  method rather than event-specific methods (i.e.
  `element.mousedown(callback)`).
- It's probably not a good idea to use a class name of `.window` for
  elements that are not the `window` object. It will cause confusion. For something like this, a class name of `stackable` or `draggable` seems appropriate.

```js
var highestZ = 3; // There are 3 divs, so highest z-index in use is initially 3
    
// When any of the div.stackable elements get clicked...
$('.stackable').on("mousedown", function () {
  $(this).css('z-index', ++highestZ);  // Clicked div gets a z-index one higher than prevous highest
});
    
// Make all ".stackable" elements resizable and draggable.
$('.stackable').draggable({containment: '#container'}).resizable({containment: '#container'});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #c9c9c9;
  font-size: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
    
.stackable {
  position: absolute !important;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-color: #222;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  user-select:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
    
#div1 { top: 20px; left: 20px; }
#div2 { top: 60px; left: 60px; }
#div3 { top: 100px; left: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="stackable" id="div1">ONE</div>
<div class="stackable" id="div2">TWO</div>
<div class="stackable" id="div3">THREE</div>
```